# Pass a prop in a Hoc function when this prop is inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components, higher-order-functions

I know the title is weird but let me explain. I have a component with props:

```
const MainExperienceComponent = props => (
  <div>
    ....
  </div>
);
```

and then I need to export it using a wrapper function like this:

```
export default withWrapper(MainExperienceComponent);
```

The problem is that I want to pass inside the `withWrapper` a prop. To be more specific I want this: `withWrapper(MainExperienceComponent, prop.id)` so as the `withWrapper` has two args. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `MainExperienceComponent` *within* the class you want to use it in (the one that has the props you want to pass) and assign it as an instance variable.

```
class Container extends Component {
  // inside the constructor:
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.WrappedComponent = withWrapper(MainExperienceComponent, props.id)
  }

  // or outside the constructor:

  WrappedComponent = withWrapper(MainExperienceComponent, this.props.id)

  render() {
    return (
      // Use <this.WrappedComponent /> here
    )
  }
}
```

Your HOC would then accept two arguments:

```
const withWrapper(WrappedComponent, id) => {
  ...
}
```

This is assuming that the `Container` component has access to the props you want to pass in. If you're passing the `id` prop into the `MainExperienceComponent` component then the HOC would already have access to it.

the caller:

```
const Wrapped = withWrapper(MainExperienceComponent)
...
<Wrapped id={someId} /> // where does someId come from?
```

the HOC:

```
const withWrapper = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class NewComponent extends Component {
    // you have access to `this.props.id`
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent />
    }
  }

  return NewComponent
}
```

If this was the case, there would be no need for passing two arguments to the HOC so I'm not sure this answers your question. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding.